# When does Object Id of Service Principal change

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have registered an app under a tenant. I was using Object Id of Service Principal that was generated. I realized that the Object Id isn't working any more & when i debugged, I realized it has changed.

Im not sure when does it change. Im not finding documentation stating the scenarios when it does change. Also, is there a way to track changes to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objectId` of a Service Principal is it's unique identifier. It should never change for the lifetime of the service principal.

So the only way you can see the objectId of a service principal changing would be that for some reason, service principal got deleted and then created again.

One possible case is a multi-tenant application where consent was already given and Service Principal got created with let's say ID1.. now if you delete the service principal and go through consent process again, service principal will be created again and hence objectId may be a new one.

Other cases could be if you're again deleting and recreating the service principal (or the application for service principal itself) through some UI or through programmatic options like PowerShell, CLI, Azure AD Graph API or Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: Excellent answer as usual Rohit. For OP: if your SP's id has changed without someone doing these, you should contact support. I had something like that happen with Outlook calendars..

Comment: Thanks @juunas .. means a lot, coming from an expert like yourself.